# Web3.js doesn't installs in mac

Tags: web3js

I tried installing web3 
Using 
Npm install web3[image: error log]
Throws an error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to downgrade python to 2.x

One way to do it:

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 2.7.14
pyenv global 2.7.14
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use a different version of web3 js library that solved the problem for me.

Comment: How to do it in terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing a specific version.
For me 1.0.0-beta.26 works fine.